# How to replace and matches a specific String with input string

Tags: c#, regex, string

My database table column contains several Strings like below mentioned:

```
---------------------------
id    |        string     |
---------------------------
1     | I love C# Code    |
---------------------------
2     | I love Java Code  |
---------------------------
3     | I love python Code|
---------------------------
4     | hello java        |
---------------------------
5     | hello c#          |
---------------------------
```

In c# each row at a time will be fetched from data base and I want to check my given pattern is matches or not.

My pattern is: `I love <anything> Code`

And I also want to replace  by another String.

I have tried:

```
foreach( string record in stringsFromDB){

    boolean isMatches=Regex.Matches(record, "I love .+? Code");

    if(isMatches){
        Console.Writeline("String matches");
    }else{
        Console.Writeline("String not matches");
    }

    string newString= Regex.Replace(record, "I love .+? Code","",, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.Writeline(newString);

}
```

Expected Result:

For matching:
For first three records it will print: String matches. For the else two print: String not matches.

And

For replacing:
For first three records it will print: I love Code. For the else two print as it is.

But nothing happen when i write code.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "But nothing happen when i write code."?

Comment: @CinCout That means always printing  String not matches and inner string is not replacing

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: You are matching whole string and replacing with blank string that's why you are getting empty response. In replace text you should pass " I love Code".

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, and you seem to suggest that your code works so far as you can run it, so please correct your example.

Comment: Note that after fixing the compile errors in your code, it seems to function as you expect. On this basis, I'm voting to close your question.

Comment: FYI to replace the language name, you can use ["zero width positive lookahead/lookbehind assertions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions): `Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=I love ).*(?= code)", "to");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

*commented* `Console.WriteLine(...)` *for clarity by OP*

```
foreach( string record in stringsFromDB) 
{
    var regexPattern = "I love .* Code";
    var match = Regex.Match(record, regexPattern);

    if(match.Success){
        Console.WriteLine("String matches");
        //Console.WriteLine("I love Code);
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("String not matches");
        //Console.WriteLine(record);
    }

    //Console.WriteLine(record); //not sure with replace I love code, is it I love code or I love <anything> code?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---------------------------
4     | hello java        |
---------------------------
5     | hello c#          |
---------------------------
```

These two are the ones not changing because they do not match the regex r"I love {anything} Code"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        var stringsFromDB = new List<string> { "I love C# Code", "I love Java Code", "I love python Code", "hello java", "hello c#" };

        foreach (string record in stringsFromDB)
        {

            bool isMatches = Regex.IsMatch(record, "I love .+? Code");

            if (isMatches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("String matches");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("String not matches");
            }

            string newString = Regex.Replace(record, "I love .+? Code", "I love Code", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Console.WriteLine(newString);

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: ... which the OP mentioned under "expected results"

Comment: Sure, updated ty